# link(url) from Google Api V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making an simple application in which I am using Google api V3, now I want it to return URI(link) of the visiting location as we can have in maps.google.com so that I can share them on social networking site. So my question is can we get URI from Google Maps Api V3 and is there any reference available ?. thank you

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V2. (tag removed)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, including Street View.

Load the same page in:

**Bozeman, MT:**
http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html?lat=45.694919&lon=-111.046151&mz=13&h=-12.68061015763454&p=4.253080718403754&z=1.33

**Gardiner, MT:**
http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html?lat=45.031865&lon=-110.705513&mz=15&h=-12.68061015763454&p=4.253080718403754&z=1.33

**Twin Falls, ID:**
http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html?lat=42.562840&lon=-114.460707&mz=15&h=51.68941136964531&p=-1.538664446192028&z=1

**Las Vegas, NV:**
http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html?lat=36.100935&lon=-115.172642&mz=16&h=-72.40679016388508&p=4.677399100624243&z=1.67

**San Francisco, CA (inside building):**
http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_streetview_search.html?lat=37.793204&lon=-122.420949&mz=18&h=-99.66403939054615&p=-2.922761229848498&z=1

Notice the "Link to this view" link on the page.